# Weird Jumping - Basic Java Game Dev

Tags: java, keylistener

[gif of the problem at hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAE1J.gif)

So as you can see in the gif, when my character jumps the first time it is a very short jump but if you make him jump immediately after landing he will spring up into the skies.

Here is the Game code:

```
package com.game.src.main;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
private Player p;
private Controller c;
private Player p2;

private boolean running = false;
private Thread thread;
long timeOfLastProjectile = 0;
long timeOfLastProjectile2 = 0;

public static final int WIDTH  = 940;
public static final int HEIGHT =  400;
public static final int SCALE = 1;
public final String TITLE = "1v1";

private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH,HEIGHT*2,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
private BufferedImage spriteSheet = null;
private BufferedImage background  = null;

private boolean is_shooting = false;
private boolean is_shooting2 = false;

public void init()
{
    BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
    try
    {
        spriteSheet = loader.loadImage("/spritesheet.png");
        background = loader.loadImage("/background.gif");
    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    addKeyListener(new KeyInput(this));
    this.requestFocus();
    p = new Player(200,(370-64),this);
    p2 = new Player((740-64),(370-64),this);
    c = new Controller(this);
}

private synchronized void start()
{
    if (running)
        return;

    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

private synchronized void stop()
{
    if (!running)
        return;

    running = false;
    try{
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(1);
}

public void run()
{
    init();
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    final double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    int updates = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(running)
    {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        if(delta >= 1)
        {
            tick();
            updates++;
            delta--;
        }
        render();
        frames++;

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000)
        {
            timer += 1000;
            System.out.println(updates + " Ticks, Fps " + frames);
            updates = 0;
            frames = 0;
        }
    }
    stop();
}

private void tick()
{
    p.tick();
    p2.tick();
    c.tick();
}

private void render()
{
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();

    if(bs == null)
    {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    ////////////////////////////////////

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);

    g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);

    p2.render(g);
    p.render(g);
    c.render(g);
    ////////////////////////////////////

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        p.setVelX(-3);
    }

    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_G) {
         p.setVelX(3);
    }

    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_R) {
        p.jump(7);
    }

    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_F)
    {
        p.setVelY(3);
    }
    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_Q && !is_shooting)
    {
        long timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long time = timeNow - timeOfLastProjectile;
        if (time < 0 || time > 1000) {
            timeOfLastProjectile = timeNow;
            is_shooting = true;
            c.addBullet(new Bullet(p.getX(), p.getY(), this, 1));
        }
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        p2.setVelX(-3);
    }

    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        p2.setVelX(3);
   }

    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        p2.setVelY(-3);
    }        

    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        p2.setVelY(3);
    }

    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_P && !is_shooting2)
    {
        long timeNow2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long time2 = timeNow2 - timeOfLastProjectile2;
        if (time2 < 0 || time2 > 1000) {
            timeOfLastProjectile2 = timeNow2;
            is_shooting2 = true;
            c.addBullet(new Bullet(p2.getX(), p2.getY(), this, 0));
        }
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        p.setVelX(0);
    }

     else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_G) {
         p.setVelX(0);
    }

    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_R) {
    }
    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_F)
    {
        p.setVelY(0);
    }
    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_Q)
    {    

        is_shooting = false;

    }
  //-------------------------------------------------------
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        p2.setVelX(0);
    }

    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        p2.setVelX(0);
   }

    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        p2.setVelY(0);
    }        

    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        p2.setVelY(0);
    }

    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_P )
    {
        is_shooting2 = false;
    }

}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Game game = new Game();

    game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
    game.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
    game.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame(game.TITLE);
    frame.add(game);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    game.start();
}

public BufferedImage getSpriteSheet()
{
    return spriteSheet;
}
```

}

and here is Player:

```
package com.game.src.main;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Player {
private double x; 
private double y;
protected double maxDY;
protected double gravity;
protected boolean canJump;

private BufferedImage player;

private double velX = 0;
private double velY = 0;
public Player(double x, double y, Game game) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    SpriteSheet ss =  new SpriteSheet(game.getSpriteSheet());
    player = ss.grabImage(1,1,32,32);
    gravity = 0.1;
    maxDY = 5;
}

private void initPlayer() {

}

public void tick()
{

    x+=velX;
    y+=velY;
    fall();
    if(x <= 0)
        x=0;

    if (x >= 940-32)
        x=940-32;

    if(y <= 0)
        y=0;

    if (y >= 370-64)
    {
        y=370-64;  
        canJump = true;
    }
    else
    {
        canJump = false;
    }
}

public void render(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(resize(player,64,64), (int)x, (int)y, null);
}

public double getX() {
    return x;
}

public double getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setX(double x)
{
    this.x = x;
}

public void setY(double y)
{
    this.y = y;
}

public void setVelX(double velX)
{
    this.velX = velX;
}

public void setVelY(double velY)
{
    this.velY = velY;
}
public static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage img, int newW, int newH) { 
    Image tmp = img.getScaledInstance(newW, newH, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    BufferedImage dimg = new BufferedImage(newW, newH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    Graphics2D g2d = dimg.createGraphics();
    g2d.drawImage(tmp, 0, 0, null);
    g2d.dispose();

    return dimg;
} 

public void fall()
{   
    if (y < 320)
    velY += gravity;
    if (velY > maxDY) velY = maxDY;
}

public void jump(double jumpHeight)
{       
    if (canJump)
        velY -= jumpHeight;
}
}
```

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with this particular bit from Player but I'm not sure:

```
public void tick()
{

    x+=velX;
    y+=velY;
    fall();
    if(x <= 0)
        x=0;

    if (x >= 940-32)
        x=940-32;

    if(y <= 0)
        y=0;

    if (y >= 370-64)
    {
        y=370-64;  
        canJump = true;
    }
    else
    {
        canJump = false;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your character doesn't have a zero vertical velocity when on the ground.  He's still falling at terminal velocity.  Your code automatically brings him up to ground level if he would go below ground, so you don't see this.  He tries to jump, and the resulting change in vertical speed overcomes this, but just barely.

But then if you jump right away when he hits the ground after a small jump, he's not yet going downward at terminal velocity - he's going down at a relatively low speed at this point.  Because his pre-jump downward velocity is smaller, his jump overcomes it easily, and he goes higher.

Comment: That's why I added if (y < 320)
     {
      velY += gravity;
      if (velY > maxDY) velY = maxDY;
     }

Comment: but that doesn't fix it

Comment: That just makes it so velY can't go more than 5.  Why is the guy traveling at a vertical rate of 5 if he's standing on the ground?  Why isn't he traveling at a rate of 0 if he's just standing there?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, turns out all I had to do was add if (y == 370-64)
        {
         velY = 0;
        }

Comment: Basically just makes it so if his y coordinate equals the ground, his velocity is 0, just like you siad

Comment: Glad to help.  You may also want to reduce your jump size now, since your jumps are going to be higher after this change, but that's up to you.

Comment: Yeah I tuned it down to 5 now